# Read text file word-by-word using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, text

I am learning LINQ, and I want to read a text file (let's say an e-book) word by word using LINQ.

This is wht I could come up with:

```
static void Main()
        {
            string[] content = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");

            var query = (from c in content
                         select content);

            foreach (var line in content)
            {
                Console.Write(line+"\n");
            }

        }
```

This reads the file line by line. If i change `ReadAllLines` to `ReadAllText`, the file is read letter by letter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines("text.txt");
var words=content.SelectMany(line=>line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
foreach(string word in words)
{
}
```

You'll need to add whatever whitespace characters you need. Using StringSplitOptions to deal with consecutive whitespaces is cleaner than the Where clause I originally used.

In .net 4 you can use File.ReadLines for lazy evaluation and thus lower RAM usage when working on large files.

Comment: the problem with this is that words in the next line are appended without space to the last word of the previous line.

Comment: Why is that a problem? The ReadAllLines function should already split these apart. And then the SelectMany splits each line even further. And the Where clause deals with consecutive whitespaces.

Comment: I think I'd prefer to split on `new Regex(@"[^\w'-]")` to catch most non-word chars but keep ' and - within words intact. If you aren't in .NET 4, you can also write your own lazy-evaluated ReadLines from a TextReader as `for(string line = rdr.ReadLine(); line != null; line = rdr.ReadLine())yield return line;`

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = File.ReadAllText();
char[] separators = { '\n', ',', '.', ' ', '"', ' ' };    // add your own
var words = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries was new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("Text.txt");

var words = from word in content.Split(WhiteSpace, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 

select word;
```

You will need to define the array of whitespace chars with your own values like so:

```
List<char> WhiteSpace = { Environment.NewLine, ' ' , '\t'};
```

This code assumes that panctuation is a part of the word (like a comma).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to read all the text using ReadAllText() then use regular expressions to get the words. Using the space character as a delimiter can cause some troubles as it will also retrieve punctuation (commas, dots .. etc). For example:

```
Regex re = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+", RegexOptions.Compiled); // You'll need to change the RE to fit your needs
Match m = re.Match(text);
while (m.Success)
{
    string word = m.Groups[1].Value;

    // do your processing here

    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses iterator blocks, and therefore uses deferred loading. Other solutions have you loading the entire file into memory before being able to iterate over the words.

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(string path){  

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path)){
        foreach (var word in line.Split(null)){
            yield return word;
        }
    }
}
```

([Split(null) automatically removes whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111298/best-way-to-specify-whitespace-in-a-string-split-operation))

Use it like this:

```
foreach (var word in GetWords(@"text.txt")){
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Works with standard Linq funness too:

```
GetWords(@"text.txt").Take(25);
GetWords(@"text.txt").Where(w => w.Length > 3)
```

Of course error handling etc. left out for sake of learning.

Answer (score -1):

You could write `content.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine))` but that's not a lot of linq.

Comment: ForEach has a return type of void- this method chaining won't compile.